# Values not appearing in CSV download

Tags: python, csv

I am using following python code to read from the text files in a folder and print in a CSV:

```
file = glob.glob(path)
for fle in file:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
    with open(fle) as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
        Date= (lines[6])
        Title=(lines[8])
        print (Date)
        print (Title)

file = glob.glob(path)
for fle in file:
    output = fle.replace('.txt', '')
    X=output
    with open(output+'_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1,lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows((name, score,Title,Date)
                            for name, score in zip(tonename, tonescore))
```

but when I open the final CSV file it only shows up with name and score and not title and date. I am pretty sure this has to do with my final loop as when I try to print date and title they do show up. I have been playing around with this a lot but could't figure it out, I would really appreciate any directions on this.

Thank You

Comment: You're not showing enough of your code. What's in the the two variables `tonename` and `tonescore`? Also need to see some input data...

Comment: Thank you, I did manage to resolve it. Modifying my answer with the change. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to resolve the issue here is the modified code :

```
for fle in file:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 

    data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')

    # iterate through tone analysis data
    tonename=[]; tonescore=[]
    for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
     for tone in cat['tones']:
            tonename.append(tone['tone_name'])
            tonescore.append(tone['score'])
            print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])
    # output tone name and score to file


file = glob.glob(path)
for fle in file:
    output = fle.replace('.txt', '') 

    with open(fle) as f:
     lines=f.readlines()
     Date= (lines[6])
     Title=(lines[8])
     X=output
    with open(output+'_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1,lineterminator='\n') 
        writer.writerows((name, score,Title,Date) for name, score in zip(tonename, tonescore))
```